# Rails::Server, Rails::Console, is there one for Rake Tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I am trying to introduce multithreading in our application with puma.

- Ruby 2.1.8
- Rails 3.2.12

I added `config.threadsafe!` to `config/application.rb` so that I could test things out in development, and from what I was reading it was good to add in general, as it locks every shared variable within a Mutex.

https://bearmetal.eu/theden/how-do-i-know-whether-my-rails-app-is-thread-safe-or-not/

This configuration is know to cause issues with rake tasks, no code is eager loaded, tons of uninitialized constants.

I stubbled across this recommendation:

```
config.threadsafe! unless $rails_rake_task
```

However:

```
puts "*" * 10
puts $rails_rake_task
puts "*" * 10
config.threadsafe! unless $rails_rake_task
```

Then running the command:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production # development eager loads anyways
```

Output:

```
**********

**********
```

The recommended variable is not defined.

I am aware that there are special modules in Rails whenever you use a console over a server.

Ex:

```
rails c
defined?(Rails::Console)
=> "constant"
defined?(Rails::Server)
=> nil

rails s
defined?(Rails::Server)
=> "constant"
defined?(Rails::Console)
=> nil
```

Is there something like this for rake tasks?

Kind of running out of ideas here, expect for overriding stuff I'd really rather not touch.

Currently I am doing:

```
config.threadsafe! if defined?(Rails::Server)
```

Which is fine, but I would rather exclude rake tasks explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
config.threadsafe! unless defined?(Rake::VERSION)
```

Comment: Nice this is exactly what I wanted! I ended up dropping the `VERSION`, since it doesn't seem to matter.